# Validating Javascript Form in this conditions statements?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm only a 5th semester IT student which is just starting to learn web programming, and I have to validate an ***address textarea*** in condition like this:

Address:

- must be filled.
- should be more than 14 characters.
- must start with word ‘Street’.
- is alphanumeric only.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Baggy Bag Shop Membership Registration</title>
    <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
      function validasi() {
        var nama = document.getElementById("nama");
        var password = document.getElementById("password");
        var konfirmasi = document.getElementById("konfirmasi");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
        var radio1 = document.getElementById("male").checked;
        var radio2 = document.getElementById("female").checked;
        var address = document.getElementById("address");
        var agreement = document.getElementById("agreement");


        if (nama.value == "") {
          alert("Please fill in your name!");
          return false;
        }

        if ((nama.value).length < 7) {
          alert("Username must be more than 6 characters.");
          return false;
        }

        if (password.value == "") {
          alert("Please fill your password");
          return false;
        }

        if ((password.value).length < 8) {
          alert("Password length must be more than 7 characters.");
          return false;
        }

        if (konfirmasi.value == "") {
          alert("Enter the password confirmation!");
          return false;
        }

        if (konfirmasi.value != password.value) {
          alert("Password confirmation does not match!");
          return false;
        }

        if (email.value == "") {
          alert("Please enter your E-Mail address!");
          return false;
        }

        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

        if (reg.test(email.value) == false) {
          alert('Invalid email address');
          return false;
        }

        if (phone.value == "") {
          alert("Please fill out your phone number");
          return false;
        }

        if (isNaN(phone.value)) {
          alert("Invalid Phone number!");
          return false;
        }

        if ((radio1 == "") && (radio2 == "")) {
          alert("Please state your gender");
          return false;
        }



        if (agreement.checked != 1) {
          alert("You must agree to the terms and conditions");
          return false;
        }

      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">~Baggy Bag Shop~
        <div id="logo">
          <img src="handbag3.jpg" height="130px" width="300px" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="menu">
        <h2>  Menu</h2>

            <h3><ul><li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li><br>
                    <li><a href="product.html">Products</a></li><br>
                    <li><a href="registration.html">Registration</a></li><br>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li><br>
                    <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li> <ul></h3>
      </div>
      <div id="contentarea">
         <h1>Create a membership for our newsletter and get special offers!</h1>

        <form name="membership" action="afterregis.html" method="get" onsubmit="return validasi();">
          <table align="center">
            <tr>
              <td>Name:</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="nama" id="nama" placeholder="Enter Username" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Password:</td>
              <td>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Confirm Password:</td>
              <td>
                <input type="password" name="konfirmasi" id="konfirmasi" placeholder="Confirm your Password" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>E-mail Address:</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter an Email Address" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Phone:</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Gender:</td>
              <td>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" />Male
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" />Female</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Address:</td>
              <td>
                <textarea cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Terms & Condition:</td>
              <td>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" readonly>By becoming a member, your data will be used for the sole purpose of Baggy Bag Shop in anyway, including selling it to a third party.</textarea>
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="agreement" id="agreement" />I Agreed with the above Terms & Conditions.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="return validasi" />
              </td>
              <td align="left">
                <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="RESET" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <p>Copyright&copy;2014</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, so now we have some code. What is the exact issue now? You have code to test it is blank. Now test the indexOf("Street")==0 and that  .length>=1 && .length<=14

Comment: i'm sorry i don't really know how to put that code in the condition statement section, i'm really new at this, the "if" function to be exact

Comment: Duplicate one of the ifs for example phone  and change phone to street and test street.value.length and so on

Comment: if (address.value.length <1 || address.length > 14) ...

Comment: huft, still won't work....

Comment: Against my principles I answered - please read and learn the techniques I have added. They are canonical for form validation

Answer (score 0):

1. NEVER call a form object "submit"
2. NEVER add an event handler to a submit button, instead add it to the form submit event
3. You had TWO validations, one on the button and one inline on the submit event

Here is how to add the events in the onload event - also note I added id="address" to the textarea and fixed the test for booleans for the gender buttons and agreement checkbox

```js
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("membership").onsubmit = function() {
        var nama = document.getElementById("nama");
        var password = document.getElementById("password");
        var konfirmasi = document.getElementById("konfirmasi");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
        var radio1 = document.getElementById("male").checked;
        var radio2 = document.getElementById("female").checked;
        var address = document.getElementById("address");
        var agreement = document.getElementById("agreement");


        if (nama.value == "") {
          alert("Please fill in your name!");
          return false;
        }

        if (nama.value.length < 7) {
          alert("Username must be more than 6 characters.");
          return false;
        }

        if (password.value == "") {
          alert("Please fill your password");
          return false;
        }

        if (password.value.length < 8) {
          alert("Password length must be more than 7 characters.");
          return false;
        }

        if (konfirmasi.value == "") {
          alert("Enter the password confirmation!");
          return false;
        }

        if (konfirmasi.value != password.value) {
          alert("Password confirmation does not match!");
          return false;
        }

        if (email.value == "") {
          alert("Please enter your E-Mail address!");
          return false;
        }

        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

        if (reg.test(email.value) == false) {
          alert('Invalid email address');
          return false;
        }

        if (phone.value == "") {
          alert("Please fill out your phone number");
          return false;
        }

        if (isNaN(phone.value)) {
          alert("Invalid Phone number!");
          return false;
        }

        if (!radio1 && !radio2) {
          alert("Please state your gender");
          return false;
        }

        if (address.value == "") {
          alert("Please fill your address");
          return false;
        }

        if (address.value.length < 14) {
          alert("Address length must be more than 14 characters.");
          return false;
        }

        if (address.value.indexOf("Street")==-1) {
          alert("Address must start with \"Street\".");
          return false;
        }

        if (!agreement.checked) {
          alert("You must agree to the terms and conditions");
          return false;
        }
        return true; // allow submit
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">~Baggy Bag Shop~
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="handbag3.jpg" height="130px" width="300px" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
    <h2>  Menu</h2>
    <h3>
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li><br>
                 <li><a href="product.html">Products</a></li><br>
                 <li><a href="registration.html">Registration</a></li><br>
                 <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li><br>
                 <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
             <ul>
         </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="contentarea">
    <h1>Create a membership for our newsletter and get special offers!</h1>
    <form id="membership" action="afterregis.html" method="get">
      <table align="center">
        <tr>
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="nama" id="nama" placeholder="Enter Username" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Confirm Password:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="password" name="konfirmasi" id="konfirmasi" placeholder="Confirm your Password" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>E-mail Address:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter an Email Address" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Phone:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gender:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" />Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" />Female</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Address:</td>
          <td>
            <textarea id="address" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Terms & Condition:</td>
          <td>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" readonly>By becoming a member, your data will be used for the sole purpose of Baggy Bag Shop in anyway, including selling it to a third party.</textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="agreement" id="agreement" />I Agreed with the above Terms & Conditions.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
          </td>
          <td align="left">
            <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="RESET" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>Copyright&copy;2014</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: also do you know to make a condition where is should be alphabetic only, or alphanumeric?

Comment: 1) I am not a "lad" 2) search SO or google for alphabetic javascript - you need to do your own homework :)